# Other methods to save data than PlayerPrefs?

Tags: unity, security, data

I've been saving data using the playerPrefs option in Unity till now.
Is there any better/secure way of saving data for developing mobile games.
Somes sites have mentioned encryption of data - how do I approach that?

Comment: You have the entirety of System.IO for reading & writing arbitrary files to Application.persistentDataPath. What have you tried so far? Note that encryption isn't really a hard wall when you're storing locally - the user's phone has both the lock and the key, so they can put them together to read/modify data stored locally. If security is important to you, then you'll need to consider options that make use of a server, so the key and lock don't both reside on the user's device.

Comment: Yes, I have read up on encryption systems, I'm just curious as to how most of the apps on the arcade market store their hi-scores?
For example, how do games like 'Dunk-Hit', or 'Sine Line' ,etc store their data. Do the big apps all use server encryption? I think not, as they can be played offline and the hi-score still gets updated!

Comment: If they're leaderboards that other players can compare, then it's probably on a server, with only a cached copy on the phone. If they're just local high scores, then who cares it the player modifies it?

Comment: Hmm however, suppose I have unlockable things via a high-score then those things could be accessed by just changed the high score. However I see your point that , if you want more security you will have to go for a client-server approach